# jackson jaxb annotations support in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jaxb, jackson

i'm looking for the simplest way of adding jaxb annotations support to jackson. 
Jackson is added now to Spring by `<mvc:annotation-driven/>`. I need that by `@ResponseBody` annotation the Object is converted to xml or json dependently to the media type.
I'm new in spring-mvc so doesn't understand well yet how things work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I assume you want to be able to return both XML and JSON. To do this you need to create `MessageConverter`s for both formats.

The XML message converter:

```
<bean id="xmlConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="jaxb2Marshaller">
            <!-- you must either bind your JAXB annotated classes here -->
            <!-- OR provide a jaxb.index and use contextPath -->
            <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.mycompany.MyClass"/>
        </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="application"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1" value="xml"/>
                <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The JSON message converter, which uses the JAXB annotations:

```
<bean id="jaxbAnnotationInspector"
    class="org.codehaus.jackson.xc.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector"/>
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="annotationIntrospector" ref="jaxbAnnotationInspector"/>
</bean>
<bean id="jsonConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="objectMapper">
        <bean ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
    </property>
    <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="application"/>
                <constructor-arg index="1" value="json"/>
                <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8"/>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And finally, the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, which will convert the responses to the appropriate content type, depending upon the accept headers:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="xmlConverter"/>
            <ref bean="jsonConverter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Note that the JAXB support in jackson isn't 100% complete or correct all the time, but the developers are really good at fixing bugs and responding to error reports.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works (It seems verbose however :). Now, i don't want to provide a list of all my JAXB annotated classes manually (for xml converter). What can i do? How it is implemented in <mvc:annotation-driven/> ?

Comment: As noted in the snippet above, you can either list all the classes or provide a `jaxb.index`. The [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance%28java.lang.String%29) indicate that you can alternatively provide an `ObjectFactory` class. It seems even more archaic and verbose to have to do that, so I just list all my classes explicitly in the spring context XML.

Comment: Oh, and if you don't like the verbosity of the XML, you could always create your own java class to arrange all the components and inject that class instead. I prefer the XML variant.